# How can I use UDP connection in Unity to send coordinate data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, udp

I am totally new to this, so pls be kind :)

I have tried to send coordinate data between two computers via Unity. I created an Unity project which consist 2 scripts (Sender and Receiver) connected to 2 gameobjects. As far as I see, I can send the data but somehow the receiver doesn`t get it. I checked the IPadresses and the port numbers by sending ping over console. It showed the same result (Sender is sending but receiver is not receiving.)

Then I tried to do it on one computer to control it better. I used localhost IPadress (127.0.0.1). I faced the same problem without getting any errors from the code.

Is there anyone that can check the code and see if there is a problem with it?

This is the sender code ;

```
    private UdpClient udpClient;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint;
    private string ipAdress = "127.0.0.1";
    private int port = 5000;

    private void Start()
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        remoteEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdress), port);
                
    }

    private void Update()
    { 
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Key is pressed");
            Vector3 coordinates = new Vector3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
            string coordinatesString = coordinates.ToString();
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(coordinatesString);
            udpClient.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndpoint);
               

            Debug.Log("Data sent:  " + data);
        }
        
    }
```

and this is the receiver code ;

```
        private UdpClient udpClient;
        private IPEndPoint localEndpoint;
        private string ipAdress = "127.0.0.1";
        private int port = 5001;
        private void Start()
        {
            udpClient = new UdpClient();
            localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdress), port);
    
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            
            if (udpClient.Available > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Client available");
                byte[] receivedData = udpClient.Receive(ref localEndpoint);
                string receivedMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData);
                Debug.Log("Received data" + receivedMessage);                 
    
            }
                
    
        }
```

I see the "Key is pressed" and "Data sent: " messages in console.However I don`t see "Client available" or "Received data" messages.

Comment: Afaik other than TCP you can not have a sender and receiver for UDP running on the same port on the same device ... could you share more context of your code and how you initialize the `udpClient`s

Comment: thanks for answering! I used different ports (5000 and 50001). I will add the codes above.

Comment: If you use different ports they will not be communicating to each other ... you are listening to packages arriving at port `5001` but you send them to `5000` ... You need to locally bind the sender to `5000` but send to "remote" port `5001` in order to receive packages at `5001` ;)